# Upload Image to Amazon S3 with Flask-admin

Tags: amazon-web-services, python-2.7, amazon-s3, flask-admin

I am using Flask-Admin and is very happy with it. However, the sample in Flask-Admin only provides to upload the image to static folder. Is it possible to upload it to S3 directly with Flask-Admin? Thanks.

Regards
Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for your sample code, Alex Chan. I needed this functionality too, so I decided to write more complete `S3FileUploadField` and `S3ImageUploadField` classes, based on your code and various other snippets.

You can find my code at:

https://github.com/Jaza/flask-admin-s3-upload

Also up on pypi, so you can install with:

`pip install flask-admin-s3-upload`

I've documentated a basic usage example in the readme (can see it on the github project page). Hope this helps, for anyone else who needs S3 file uploads in flask-admin.

Answer (score 4):

Here it is but not clean the code..

```
import os
import os.path as op
import cStringIO
import logging
import config
from flask import url_for

from werkzeug import secure_filename
from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage
import boto
from boto.s3.key import Key

from wtforms import ValidationError, fields
from wtforms.widgets import HTMLString, html_params

from flask.ext.admin.babel import gettext

from flask.ext.admin._compat import string_types, urljoin
from flask.ext.admin.form.upload import ImageUploadField


try:
    from PIL import Image, ImageOps
except ImportError:
    Image = None
    ImageOps = None

__all__ = ['FileUploadInput', 'FileUploadField',
           'ImageUploadInput', 'ImageUploadField',
           'namegen_filename', 'thumbgen_filename']


class ImageUploadInput(object):
    """
        Renders a image input chooser field.

        You can customize `empty_template` and `data_template` members to customize
        look and feel.
    """
    empty_template = ('<input %(file)s>')

    data_template = ('<div class="image-thumbnail">'
                     ' <img %(image)s>'
                     ' <input type="checkbox" name="%(marker)s">Delete</input>'
                     '</div>'
                     '<input %(file)s>')

    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('id', field.id)
        kwargs.setdefault('name', field.name)

        args = {
            'file': html_params(type='file',
                                **kwargs),
            'marker': '_%s-delete' % field.name
        }

        if field.data and isinstance(field.data, string_types):
            url = self.get_url(field)
            args['image'] = html_params(src=url)

            template = self.data_template
        else:
            template = self.empty_template

        return HTMLString(template % args)

    def get_url(self, field):
        if field.thumbnail_size:
            filename = field.thumbnail_fn(field.data)
        else:
            filename = field.data

        if field.url_relative_path:
            filename = urljoin(field.url_relative_path, filename)
        return field.data
        #return url_for(field.endpoint, filename=field.data)




class s3ImageUploadField(ImageUploadField):
    """
        Image upload field.

        Does image validation, thumbnail generation, updating and deleting images.

        Requires PIL (or Pillow) to be installed.
    """
    widget = ImageUploadInput()

    keep_image_formats = ('PNG',)
    """
        If field detects that uploaded image is not in this list, it will save image
        as PNG.
    """

    def __init__(self, label=None, validators=None,
                 base_path=None, relative_path=None,
                 namegen=None, allowed_extensions=None,
                 max_size=None,
                 thumbgen=None, thumbnail_size=None,
                 permission=0o666,
                 url_relative_path=None, endpoint='static',
                 **kwargs):
        """
            Constructor.

            :param label:
                Display label
            :param validators:
                Validators
            :param base_path:
                Absolute path to the directory which will store files
            :param relative_path:
                Relative path from the directory. Will be prepended to the file name for uploaded files.
                Flask-Admin uses `urlparse.urljoin` to generate resulting filename, so make sure you have
                trailing slash.
            :param namegen:
                Function that will generate filename from the model and uploaded file object.
                Please note, that model is "dirty" model object, before it was committed to database.

                For example::

                    import os.path as op

                    def prefix_name(obj, file_data):
                        parts = op.splitext(file_data.filename)
                        return secure_filename('file-%s%s' % parts)

                    class MyForm(BaseForm):
                        upload = FileUploadField('File', namegen=prefix_name)

            :param allowed_extensions:
                List of allowed extensions. If not provided, will allow any file.
            :param max_size:
                Tuple of (width, height, force) or None. If provided, Flask-Admin will
                resize image to the desired size.
            :param thumbgen:
                Thumbnail filename generation function. All thumbnails will be saved as JPEG files,
                so there's no need to keep original file extension.

                For example::

                    import os.path as op

                    def thumb_name(filename):
                        name, _ = op.splitext(filename)
                        return secure_filename('%s-thumb.jpg' % name)

                    class MyForm(BaseForm):
                        upload = ImageUploadField('File', thumbgen=prefix_name)

            :param thumbnail_size:
                Tuple or (width, height, force) values. If not provided, thumbnail won't be created.

                Width and height is in pixels. If `force` is set to `True`, will try to fit image into dimensions and
                keep aspect ratio, otherwise will just resize to target size.
            :param url_relative_path:
                Relative path from the root of the static directory URL. Only gets used when generating
                preview image URLs.

                For example, your model might store just file names (`relative_path` set to `None`), but
                `base_path` is pointing to subdirectory.
            :param endpoint:
                Static endpoint for images. Used by widget to display previews. Defaults to 'static'.
        """
        # Check if PIL is installed
        if Image is None:
            raise Exception('PIL library was not found')

        self.max_size = max_size
        self.thumbnail_fn = thumbgen or thumbgen_filename
        self.thumbnail_size = thumbnail_size
        self.endpoint = endpoint
        self.image = None
        self.url_relative_path = url_relative_path

        if not allowed_extensions:
            allowed_extensions = ('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'tiff')

        super(ImageUploadField, self).__init__(label, validators,
                                               base_path=base_path,
                                               relative_path=relative_path,
                                               namegen=namegen,
                                               allowed_extensions=allowed_extensions,
                                               permission=permission,
                                               **kwargs)

    def pre_validate(self, form):
        super(ImageUploadField, self).pre_validate(form)

        if self.data and isinstance(self.data, FileStorage):
            try:
                self.image = Image.open(self.data)
            except Exception as e:
                raise ValidationError('Invalid image: %s' % e)

    # Deletion
    def _delete_file(self, filename):
        super(ImageUploadField, self)._delete_file(filename)

        self._delete_thumbnail(filename)

    def _delete_thumbnail(self, filename):
        path = self._get_path(self.thumbnail_fn(filename))

        if op.exists(path):
            os.remove(path)

    # Saving
    def _save_file(self, data, filename):
        path = self._get_path(filename)

        if not op.exists(op.dirname(path)):
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(path), self.permission)

        # Figure out format
        filename, format = self._get_save_format(filename, self.image)

        if self.image and (self.image.format != format or self.max_size):
            if self.max_size:
                image = self._resize(self.image, self.max_size)
            else:
                image = self._resize(self.image, (500, 500))
                #image = self.image

            self._save_image(image, filename, format)
        else:
            data.seek(0)
            data.save(path)
        savedUrl=self._save_image(self.image, filename, format)
        self._save_thumbnail(data, filename, format)

        return savedUrl

    def _save_thumbnail(self, data, filename, format):
        if self.image and self.thumbnail_size:
            path = self._get_path(self.thumbnail_fn(filename))

            savedUrl=self._save_image(self._resize(self.image, self.thumbnail_size),
                             thumbgen_filename(filename),
                             format)
            return savedUrl

    def _resize(self, image, size):
        (width, height, force) = size

        if image.size[0] > width or image.size[1] > height:
            if force:
                return ImageOps.fit(self.image, (width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            else:
                thumb = self.image.copy()
                thumb.thumbnail((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
                return thumb

        return image

    def _save_image(self, image, path, format='JPEG'):
        if image.mode not in ('RGB', 'RGBA'):
            image = image.convert('RGBA')

        conn =boto.connect_s3( config.AWS_KEY, config.AWS_SECRET,)
        bucket = conn.get_bucket("vipbutton")
        k = Key(bucket)
        k.key= path
        tempFile = cStringIO.StringIO()
        image.save(tempFile,format)
        #image.seek(0)
        #tempFile.seek(0)
        #k.set_contents_from_string('This is a test of S3')
        k.set_contents_from_string(tempFile.getvalue())
        k.set_acl('public-read')
        #k.set_contents_from_file(tempFile.getValue())
        #with open(path, 'wb') as fp:
        #    image.save(fp, format)
        return k.generate_url(expires_in=0, query_auth=False)

    def _get_save_format(self, filename, image):
        if image.format not in self.keep_image_formats:
            name, ext = op.splitext(filename)
            filename = '%s.jpg' % name
            return filename, 'JPEG'

        return filename, image.format


# Helpers
def namegen_filename(obj, file_data):
    """
        Generate secure filename for uploaded file.
    """
    return secure_filename(file_data.filename)


def thumbgen_filename(filename):
    """
        Generate thumbnail name from filename.
    """
    name, ext = op.splitext(filename)
    return '%s_thumb%s' % (name, ext)
```